# Demerit of using IE=edge in html pages

Tags: html, internet-explorer, x-ua-compatible, metatag

I am using `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">`in my application.
It will choose the latest version of IE installed in the machine to render.

Is there any disadvantage of using this `<meta>` tag ?

Comment: Well, if you have workarounds for specific IE bugs in your HTML page, say in IE8, and the next version of IE has fixed those bugs, it will no longer display the page the way you wanted. Unless you write `IE=8` in your meta element.

Comment: That said, we keep finding more ad more differences between IE10 in IE8 mode and IE8 itself, so there is no guarantee that IE10 will display your page exactly like IE8 did.

Answer (score 0):

This meta tag will make your code W3C invalid on HTML5